# SqlDataSource and DateTime fields

Tags: asp.net, datetime, sqldatasource

I'm having an issue with the `SqlDataSource` object and having it store dates and times in SQL Server (2005).

The data source (I've excluded the bits that work properly):

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="dataRequest" runat="server" 
  SelectCommand="request_select"  SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" 
  InsertCommand="request_insert"  InsertCommandType="StoredProcedure" 
  UpdateCommand="request_update"  UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure"
  >
    <SelectParameters>
        <!-- This section work fine -->
        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="requestid"  Type="Int32" QueryStringField="requestid" />
    </SelectParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="requestid"             Type="Int32"    />
        <!-- Lots of parameters here that work fine -->
        <asp:Parameter Name="date_new_req"          Type="DateTime" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="date_new_acc"          Type="DateTime" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="date_quote_req"        Type="DateTime" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="date_quote_acc"        Type="DateTime" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="date_bh_approve_req"   Type="DateTime" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="date_bh_approve_acc"   Type="DateTime" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="date_work_req"         Type="DateTime" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="date_work_acc"         Type="DateTime" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="date_complete_req"     Type="DateTime" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="date_complete_acc"     Type="DateTime" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="date_declined_req"     Type="DateTime" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="date_declined_acc"     Type="DateTime" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="date_bh_declined_req"  Type="DateTime" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="date_bh_declined_acc"  Type="DateTime" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="date_archived_req"     Type="DateTime" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="requestor_ntlog"       Type="String"   />
    </UpdateParameters>
    <InsertParameters>
        <!-- This section works fine -->
    </InsertParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

The dates are simply displayed in text boxes with a 'stamp' button beside them to stamp the current date and time into them.  Each text box is data bound to the `SqlDataSource` and resides within a `FormView`. On update the rest of the `FormView`'s information is submitted properly, including text fields, numeric fields (from both text boxes and DDL's) and check boxes.

```
<asp:FormView ID="requestProcessing" runat="server" DefaultMode="ReadOnly"
    DataSourceID="dataRequest" DataKeyNames="requestid"
    CssClass="editPanel" BorderStyle="None" EnableViewState="true">

    <!-- There's loads of stuff within the FormView, but I've omitted it as it's irrelevant to this issue, but will post if necessary -->

    <table class="dateTable" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="prompt">
                <asp:Label   ID="date_new_req_update_label" runat="server" Text="New job request" AssociatedControlID="date_new_req_update" /><br />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="date_new_req_update" Text='<%# Bind("date_new_req") %>' CssClass="dataEntry" MaxLength="25" />
                <a href="javascript:stampNow('requestProcessing_date_new_req_update')" class="dateButton">stamp</a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="date_new_acc_update" Text='<%# Bind("date_new_acc") %>' CssClass="dataEntry" MaxLength="25" />
                <a href="javascript:stampNow('requestProcessing_date_new_acc_update')" class="dateButton">stamp</a>
            </td>
        </tr>                
        <tr id="row2" runat="server">
            <td class="prompt">
                <asp:Label   runat="server" ID="date_quote_req_update_label" Text="Date of quote" AssociatedControlID="date_quote_req_update" />
            </td>            
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="date_quote_req_update" Text='<%# Bind("date_quote_req") %>' CssClass="dataEntry" MaxLength="25" />
                <a href="javascript:stampNow('requestProcessing_date_quote_req_update')" class="dateButton">stamp</a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="date_quote_acc_update" Text='<%# Bind("date_quote_acc") %>' CssClass="dataEntry" MaxLength="25" />
                <a href="javascript:stampNow('requestProcessing_date_quote_acc_update')" class="dateButton">stamp</a>
            </td>
        </tr>                
        <tr id="row3" runat="server">
            <td class="prompt">
                <asp:Label   runat="server" ID="date_bh_approve_req_update_label" Text="Budget holder alerted" AssociatedControlID="date_bh_approve_req_update" />
            </td>            
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="date_bh_approve_req_update" Text='<%# Bind("date_bh_approve_req") %>' CssClass="dataEntry" MaxLength="25" />
                <a href="javascript:stampNow('requestProcessing_date_bh_approve_req_update')" class="dateButton">stamp</a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="date_bh_approve_acc_update" Text='<%# Bind("date_bh_approve_acc") %>' CssClass="dataEntry" MaxLength="25" />
                <a href="javascript:stampNow('requestProcessing_date_bh_approve_acc_update')" class="dateButton">stamp</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <!-- I've omitted a lot of the dates here as they've all been tested and give the same result ... nothing! -->
    </tbody>

    </table>

</asp:FormView>
```

In the `web.config` I've included a globalisation line specifically for the UK (just in case).

```
<globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" culture="en-GB" uiCulture="en-GB"/>
```

The only code behind initiated by the update process sends a mail to a requestor:

```
Private Sub UpdateComplete(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As FormViewUpdatedEventArgs) Handles requestProcessing.ItemUpdated
    If CType(requestProcessing.FindControl("mailUser"), CheckBox).Checked Then
        Dim body As New StringBuilder()
        With e.NewValues
            'Notify the user of changes to the current request...
            body.Append("<p>Changes have been made to your job request (")
            body.Append(.Item("requestid").ToString())
            body.Append(").</p>")
            body.Append("<p>If you would like to review the changes to your job, please click ")
            body.Append("<a href='")
            body.Append(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority))
            body.Append("/default.aspx?requestid=")
            body.Append(.Item("requestid").ToString())
            body.Append("&mode=select'>Click this link to view your job.</a>")
            body.Append("<p>With kind regards,<br /><strong>The Minor New Works Team</strong></p>")
            Functions.BuildEmail(CType(.Item("requestid"), Int32), True, False, "", _
               "Changes have been made to your job request", body.ToString(), _
               Functions.LocalMailFlagsEnum.BasicBody Or Functions.LocalMailFlagsEnum.VerboseSubject)
            'Check to see if budget holder acceptance should be requested...
            If Not .Item("date_bh_approve_req") Is Nothing AndAlso _
               Not e.OldValues.Item("date_bh_approve_req") Is Nothing AndAlso _
               .Item("date_bh_approve_req").ToString() <> "" AndAlso _
               e.OldValues.Item("date_bh_approve_req").ToString() = "" Then
                Functions.NotifyBudgetHolder(CType(.Item("requestid"), Int32))
            End If
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

I've tested each of the stored procedures necessary to both pull and push information and they work fine, producing the required results.  Also, I've added a logging routine to capture the parameters passed to the stored procedure; on manual execution all parameters are logged to the log table, whereas on execution from the ASP.NET page the dates are excluded.

If anyone could shine any light on this issue or has experienced similar problems I'd love to hear about it.

-- EDIT --
This is ASP.NET 3.5

Comment: What type are those columns in SQL Server?  Have you tried eliminating the stroed procedure as the culprit by placing the SQL Update statement directly in the `UpdateCommand`?

Comment: @jadarnel27: Thanks for the reply. Yes - I've tested the SP and everything runs through fine.  The types in the database are `DATETIME`.  The problem appears to happen somewhere in the transfer of data from the controls to the `SqlDataSource`, or as the elements are being translated from the text format of the `TextBox` to the required `DateTime` format.  Basically, no dates reach SQL Server.  Bit of a puzzler this one!

Comment: I've started building a test form to test the data throughput.  I'm going to build this up until I get the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.  This took a while, but I've found the problem.

For some reason ASP.NET didn't like the format of the table that I'd placed the `TextBox` elements in.

For now I'll take them out and have a play with the format.  The table isn't imperative; it's simply the way I wanted to present the tabular form of this data, so I'll sort that out as soon as I've got a few minutes.

**-- Edit --**

Just to further this, I've tried several different formats of table within the `FormView` control and found exactly the same issue each time, even with ASP.NET's own `Table` control.